# How to set use_sim_time

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, use-sim-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am wondering how you can set use_sim_time to true, or enable it for my nodes. Do I have to do it within my nodes? or in my launch file? Also, is this something you must do for all your nodes and/or launch files? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325667/how-to-set-use_sim_time/) by [GabrielBagon44](https://answers.ros.org/users/42069/gabrielbagon44/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you need to set `use_sim_time` from the commandline, then `rosparam` is your friend. Please read https://wiki.ros.org/rosparam

If you need to set it from a launch file, you can use either the `<rosparam>` tag to read a yaml file of parameters (https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) or you can use the `<param>` tag to set a particular parameter, like `use_sim_time` (https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param). For example, add `<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />`

Reading the documentation helps alot.

Also helpful is the documentation regarding the ros clock: https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam

You only need to set the `/use_sim_time` (note that it is in the root namespace) parameter once, and all your nodes will start using simulation time.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2019-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GabrielBagon44](https://answers.ros.org/users/42069/gabrielbagon44/) on 2019-06-13**:
Thanks for the informative response!

**Comment by [FantasticMrFox](https://answers.ros.org/users/67692/fantasticmrfox/) on 2021-08-05**:
The example: `<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true">` is missing the closing /. If you copy paste this, use: `<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>`

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2022-02-01**:
Applied @FantasticMrFox's suggestion to add closing slash.